# How can i add element in explicit wait statement in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
    WebElement statusArr[]=new WebElement[6];
    String arr[] = new String[6];       
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        int j = i+1;
        statusArr[i] = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='body']/ui-view/div[1]/div/div["+j+"]/a/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/i"));
        arr[i] = statusArr[i].getAttribute("title");
    }
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i].equals("Not Provided")||arr[i].equals("Incomplete")){
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfNestedElementsLocatedBy(statusArr[i], null));
            statusArr[i].click();
            driver.navigate().back();
        }
    }
```

Here i am trying to wait for the element to load and then click. But it is not possible. How can I do this?

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML and describe the scenario you are trying to accomplish. I think there's probably a better way to do this. That XPath locator is going to be very brittle as long as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `visibilityOfNestedElementsLocatedBy` [docs](http://javadox.com/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support/2.53.0/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfNestedElementsLocatedBy-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-)

> An expectation for checking child WebElement as a part of parent element to be visible

In `visibilityOfNestedElementsLocatedBy(statusArr[i], null)` you are basically waiting for `null` to be visible. Try `visibilityOf` instead

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(statusArr[i]));
```

By the way, when you click on the element and navigate back you will loose the elements in `statusArr[]` and you will have to relocate them each iteration.

Comment: What should i do about navigate then?
If i relocate elements each time in iteration then how can I get the count number for which the loop was iterating?

Comment: @AniruddhaSupe Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366251/get-staleelementreferenceexception-error-while-using-driver-navigate-back-in/38366373#38366373